# simple function that gets href link from html returning undefined, but prints link when asked to

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends links. I have this code that scrapes a website and sends the href link to discord.

```
function scrapeForLink(recievedMessage){
    let scienceDailyURL = "https://www.sciencedaily.com";
    let link;

     request("https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/computers_math/artificial_intelligence/",
        (error, response, html) => {
            let success = !error && response.statusCode === 200;

            if (success){
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                link = $('#featured_tab_1').find('.latest-head').find('a').attr('href');
        }
        recievedMessage.channel.send(scienceDailyURL + link);
        console.log(scienceDailyURL + link)
}
```

When this function executes, it works, it sends the link and it prints it to console, however when i try to return it (which I need to for later progress in the bot), it returns undefined:

```
function scrapeForLink(recievedMessage){
    let link;
    let scienceDailyURL = "https://www.sciencedaily.com";

    request("https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/computers_math  /artificial_intelligence/",
    (error, response, html) => {
        let success = !error && response.statusCode === 200;

        if (success){
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            link = $('#featured_tab_1').find('.latest-    head').find('a').attr('href');
    }
    recievedMessage.channel.send(scienceDailyURL + link);
    return(scienceDailyURL + link);
}
```

When this is executed, it still sends the link but when i print the function to the console, it returns undefined

This is the function when it is executed:

```
function processCommand(recievedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = recievedMessage.content.substr(1);
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ");
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0];
    let args = splitCommand.slice(1);

    if (primaryCommand === "multiply") {
        multiplyCommand(args, recievedMessage)
    }
    else if (primaryCommand === "github"){
        recievedMessage.channel.send("https://github.com/Pacutacatete100/AINewsBot/blob/master/MediaBot.js")
    }
    else if (primaryCommand === "add") {
        addCommand(args, recievedMessage)
    }
    else if(primaryCommand === "factorial"){
        factorial(args, recievedMessage)
    }
    else  if (primaryCommand === "news"){
        scrapeForLink(recievedMessage)//this is where i call the function, 
//if i am trying to print the value of the function would do console.log(scrapeForLink(recievedMessage))
}
```

}

Comment: which function are you printing to console? Doesn't seem like you created a function in this code.

Comment: You aren't returning to anything, you are in an async operation callback the rest of the code outside has already executed.

Comment: whoops, I did make that function, guess I forgot to put in on  here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the value from the callback function but that value isn't be 'returned' to anything really.  The callback function (the 2nd parameter to `request`) is called when the request completes, and you get the link. If you want to work with it you should do so within the callback function.

Remember that your callback function is called by the `request` function when it has the final data, but it doesn't do anything with whatever your callback function returns.

You can use the `link` variable, and you can even set another variable to that value, but remember that since it's a callback function, it may execute well after the function that called `request` has completed.

```
let link;
let scienceDailyURL = "https://www.sciencedaily.com";

let x = request("https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/computers_math/artificial_intelligence/", 
 (error, response, html) => {
  let success = !error && response.statusCode === 200;
  if (success){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    link = $('#featured_tab_1').find('.latest-head').find('a').attr('href');
  }
  recievedMessage.channel.send(scienceDailyURL + link);
  // This is where you can go ahead and do something meaningful with 'link'
  someFunctionThatUsesLink(scienceDailyURL + link);
  // The return statement doesn't do anything since the caller is the 'request' function.
  return(scienceDailyURL + link);
});

// x will be undefined
```

Comment: If I wanted to do something similar again, would I have to also return something or is that just not needed?

Comment: Returning something is only of value if the caller of your function will use the returned value. That's not the case with callbacks. If you want to use `link` in other places you can store it in Redux, or pass it as a parameter to other functions, but it would need to be done within the body of the callback.